# SQL Server Management Studio crashes when I try to build a database diagram

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am working on a database (Local server install), that I have been working on for some time. Lately though I have had issues whenever I try to build a database diagram.

I can insert one table, but when I try to drag another table from the object explorer into the diagram (From the same database), SSMS freezes with this pop-up

[image]

My only option is to force close SSMS.

I have tried dropping and recreating the database, but same problem

I am running SSMS v. 18.1 32 bit and SQL Server 2017 64bit

I have recently updated SSMS, could it be a 32bit-64bit issue?

Comment: I have the same configuration and everything seems to work fine. Maybe to reinstall SSMS?

Comment: *"could it be a 32bit-64bit issue"* SSMS is only available in 32bit; the architecture  of SQL Server you're using (which for 2017 I believe is only 64bit) doesn't matter. Much like Excel can read an xlsx file, regardless of if it's  32bit or 64bit and regardless of what version the file was (initially) created in.

Comment: I have tried reinstalling SSMS a few times.
And dropping/recreating the entire database.

I have noticed the issue on other databases though, so I think that the server may be corrupt?